# Why is my UseEffect for making requests to Spotify API giving an error 429?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, spotify, use-effect

I am currently making a Spotify clone which gives user a preview of the song. The problem occurs when I am making many different api requests. When there are more than one requests on the page, it throws a 429 error(making too many requests at once).

##### Please read through the whole question as I have mentioned the steps I have taken to fix this below.

#### Profile.js

```js
    const { api, refreshableCall } = useSpotify()
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)
    const [userName, setUserName] = useState("")
    const [userFollowers, setUserFollowers] = useState("")
    const [userImage, setUserImage] = useState([])
    const [userLink, setUserLink] = useState("")
    const [userId, setUserId] = useState("")
    const [userFollowing, setUserFollowing] = useState("")
    const [userTopArtists, setUserTopArtists] = useState([])
    const [userTopSongs, setUserTopSongs] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        let disposed = false
        refreshableCall(() => api.getMyTopTracks({
            limit: 10,
            time_range: "long_term"
        }))
            .then((res) => {
                if (disposed) return
                setUserTopSongs(res.body.items)
                setError(null)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                if (disposed) return
                setUserTopSongs([])
                setError(err)
            });
        return () => disposed = true
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        let disposed = false
        refreshableCall(() => api.getMe())
            .then((res) => {
                if (disposed) return
                var data = res.body
                setUserName(data.display_name)
                setUserImage(data.images)
                setUserFollowers(data.followers["total"])
                setUserLink(data.external_urls.spotify)
                setUserId(data.id)
                setError(null)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                if (disposed) return
                setUserName("")
                setUserImage([])
                setUserFollowers("")
                setUserLink("")
                setUserId("")
                setError(err)
            });
        return () => disposed = true

    })

    useEffect(() => {
        let disposed = false
        refreshableCall(() => api.getFollowedArtists())
            .then((res) => {
                if (disposed) return
                var data = res.body
                var artists = data.artists
                setUserFollowing(artists.total)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                if (disposed) return
                setUserFollowing([])
                setError(err)
            });
        return () => disposed = true

    })

    useEffect(() => {
        let disposed = false
        refreshableCall(() => api.getMyTopArtists({
            limit: 10,
            time_range: "long_term"
        }))
            .then((res) => {
                if (disposed) return
                var data = res.body
                var artists = data.items
                setUserTopArtists(artists)
                setError(null)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                if (disposed) return
                setUserTopArtists([])
                setError(err)
            });
        return () => disposed = true

    })
```

#### SpotifyContext.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react"
import axios from "axios"
import SpotifyWebApi from 'spotify-web-api-node';

const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
    clientId: 1234567890,
});

export const SpotifyAuthContext = React.createContext({
    exchangeCode: () => { throw new Error("context not loaded") },
    refreshAccessToken: () => { throw new Error("context not loaded") },
    hasToken: spotifyApi.getAccessToken() !== undefined,
    api: spotifyApi
});

export const useSpotify = () => useContext(SpotifyAuthContext);

function setStoredJSON(id, obj) {
    localStorage.setItem(id, JSON.stringify(obj));
}

function getStoredJSON(id, fallbackValue = null) {
    const storedValue = localStorage.getItem(id);
    return storedValue === null
        ? fallbackValue
        : JSON.parse(storedValue);
}

export function SpotifyAuthContextProvider({ children }) {
    const [tokenInfo, setTokenInfo] = useState(() => getStoredJSON('myApp:spotify', null))

    const hasToken = tokenInfo !== null

    useEffect(() => {
        if (tokenInfo === null) return;

        // attach tokens to `SpotifyWebApi` instance
        spotifyApi.setCredentials({
            accessToken: tokenInfo.accessToken,
            refreshToken: tokenInfo.refreshToken,
        })

        // persist tokens
        setStoredJSON('myApp:spotify', tokenInfo)
    }, [tokenInfo])

    function exchangeCode(code) {
        return axios
            .post("http://localhost:3001/login", {
                code
            })
            .then(res => {
                // TODO: Confirm whether response contains `accessToken` or `access_token`
                const { accessToken, refreshToken, expiresIn } = res.data;
                // store expiry time instead of expires in
                setTokenInfo({
                    accessToken,
                    refreshToken,
                    expiresAt: Date.now() + (expiresIn * 1000)
                });
            })
    }

    function refreshAccessToken() {
        const refreshToken = tokenInfo.refreshToken;
        return axios
            .post("http://localhost:3001/refresh", {
                refreshToken
            })
            .then(res => {
                const refreshedTokenInfo = {
                    accessToken: res.data.accessToken,
                    // some refreshes may include a new refresh token!
                    refreshToken: res.data.refreshToken || tokenInfo.refreshToken,
                    // store expiry time instead of expires in
                    expiresAt: Date.now() + (res.data.expiresIn * 1000)
                }

                setTokenInfo(refreshedTokenInfo)

                // attach tokens to `SpotifyWebApi` instance
                spotifyApi.setCredentials({
                    accessToken: refreshedTokenInfo.accessToken,
                    refreshToken: refreshedTokenInfo.refreshToken,
                })

                return refreshedTokenInfo
            })
    }

    async function refreshableCall(callApiFunc) {
        if (Date.now() > tokenInfo.expiresAt)
            await refreshAccessToken();

        try {
            return await callApiFunc()
        } catch (err) {
            if (err.name !== "WebapiAuthenticationError")
                throw err; // rethrow irrelevant errors
        }

        // if here, has an authentication error, try refreshing now
        return refreshAccessToken()
            .then(callApiFunc)
    }

    return (
        <SpotifyAuthContext.Provider value={{
            api: spotifyApi,
            exchangeCode,
            hasToken,
            refreshableCall,
            refreshAccessToken
        }}>
            {children}
        </SpotifyAuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

#### Errors

1. Without the dependency, it keeps cycling and firing off requests, likely hundreds per second. (Error 429)
2. With the dependency, it seems the Access Token is being ignored or sidestepped. (Error: WebApiAuthentication - No token provided)

#### What I have tried to do ?

1. I tried to implement all the requests in a single `useEffect`, still getting the errors.
2. Calling `useEffect` with dependency array and without.

##### Link to the Github Repo

https://github.com/amoghkapoor/spotify-clone

Answer (score 0):

status 429 means you have made too many calls in a specific time window.
you are therefore banned for this specific time window.
try waiting a bit before retrying.

did you try :

```
useEffect(..., [])
```

this guaranties it will be run only once.

Comment: No, it's not that, the component is rendering properly and after a reload the API is also working properly, but the problem that I am facing is that in a single request inside ```useEffect```the api request is made about a few hundred times.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried adding a dependency array as mentioned above in the question, but when I add a dependency array, I get a different error saying that no access_token has been provided.

Answer (score 0):

None of your useEffect calls are using a dependency array, remember if useEffect is called without any dependencies it goes into an infinite loop. Either find what dependency or state change should re-run the useEffect hook and include it in the dependency array:

```js
useEffect(() => { /* your logic */ }, [dependencies])
```

or if there are no dependencies simply fire it once the component mounts:

```js
useEffect(() => { /* your logic */ }, [])
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question and in the previous answer's comment I have already tried adding a dependency array, but now it gives a different error, no access_token has been provided.

Comment: @Amogh then that is error you should fix, as the error says it explicitly `no access_token has been provided` which means you're not providing the access token somewhere. Not providing a dependency array won't solve your problem anyways, since it is wrong react code. In your spotify context make sure that your accessToken is valid.